# How to fix the IO exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a XML file where I am reading the file.When ever the I logout of the site and re-login into the site it is showing the below exception

> *The process cannot access the file '..\Uploads\demo\transaction.xml' because it is being used by another process.*
>   Based on the this XML file I am doing some data validations.Can any one help me on this ?

```
private IEnumerable<XElement> GetChildElements(string strFileName)
        {
            try
            {

                if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Filepath"] == null)
                    return null;

                     var xDocument = XDocument.Load(streamXml);
                    IEnumerable<XElement> xElements = null;
                    if (xDocument.Root != null)
                        xElements = xDocument.Root.Elements()
                            .Where(e => e.Attribute("name").Value.ToLower().Equals(strCsvFileName.ToLower()))
                            .SelectMany(c => c.Elements());

                    return xElements;




            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logging.ILogging.Error(ex);
                throw ex;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Show the code where you are opening the XML file. Most likely you're using the wrong flags, causing the first process to lock the file.

Comment: Kindly post the tried code ?

Comment: There is nothing we can do to comment on this without some code, other than to say "your file isn't closed" - but you already knew that.

Comment: Also, `XDocument` is not disposable, so any means of trying to "dispose" it, are probably wrong.

Answer (score 2):

(edited from comments)

```
var streamXml = File.OpenRead(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(strXmlFilePath));
...
var xDocument = XDocument.Load(streamXml);
```

Yeah, that's a problem; you need:

```
XDocument xDocument;
using(var streamXml = File.OpenRead(
    HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(strXmlFilePath)))
{
    xDocument = XDocument.Load(streamXml);
}
```

Or more simply:

```
var xDocument = XDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(strXmlFilePath));
```

otherwise, you haven't cleaned up correclty.

> But when trying to update the XML file it is showing the error message Stream does not support writing.

Yes, you said `OpenRead`. That opens it for reading only.

Comment: Now just now I have update the code with the below line 
var streamXml = File.OpenRead(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(strXmlFilePath));
Lastly I am closing the stream

But when trying to update the XML file it is showing the error message Stream does not support writing.

Comment: @HemantKumar oh, that changes *everything*, yeah, you're doing it wrong... you need some `using` there; see edit

Comment: Ok for updating the XML file I have tried with OpenWrite.But no use

Comment: @HemantKumar just use `XDocument.Save(string)` with the resolved path (i.e. after the `MapPath`)